# C# string to integer conversion issue

Tags: c#, string, integer, streamreader

Awhile ago, I started making a program in vb.net. Since then i've lost the code, and started using c#.
I have everything converted, except the update system I had gives me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' streamreader".

Heres the old code:

```
        Try
        Dim Build As Integer
        Build = 3

        Dim url As String
        url = "###link###"
        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"))
        Dim Online As Integer
        Online = sr.ReadToEnd()

        If Build >= Online Then
            Label10.Visible = True
        Else
            LinkLabel1.Visible = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

Here's the code i converted:

```
            try
        {
            int Build = 0; 
            Build = 3;

            string url = null;
            url = "###link###";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
            int Online = 0;
            Online = sr.ReadToEnd();

            if (Build >= Online)
            {
                Label10.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                LinkLabel1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

I've been googling for days and have found no similar errors or fixes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Online;
string onlineString = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
Online = int.Parse (onlineString);
```

There are three built-in ways to convert a string to an integer.

```
int myInt;
myInt = Convert.ToInt32 (s);
myInt = int.Parse (s); // or Int32.Parse (s); // same thing.
if (int.TryParse (s, out myInt)
    Console.WriteLine ("parse successful");
else
    Console.WriteLine ("parse failed, but no exception was thrown");
```

Answer (score 5):

[**`StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) returns a `string`, you will have to manually convert it to `int`:

```
Online = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Online = int.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 1):

`sr.ReadToEnd` returns a string. An integer cannot be converted from a string with a simple cast (apparently VB allows this). Try using `int.Parse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use TryParse to avoid any format exception s.

Try this:

```
if(Int32.TryParse(sr.ReadToEnd(), out Online))
{
    if (Build >= Online)
        {
                Label10.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
                LinkLabel1.Visible = true;
        }
}
else
{
            LinkLabel1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: definite +1 on TryParse you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 0):

[ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) returns a string. I'm not sure why you can't simply do:

```
Online = int.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
```